# Receive Multiple Grants?

Tags: united-states, college, tuition, school, scholarship

Is it possible to receive multiple grants? I was approved for a TAP grant. But is it possible to also get a Pell grant, FSEOG grant, LEAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, in general. However, it isn't uncommon for these grants to be need-based, so that even if you're accepted for several the total grant amount may not increase as much as you might expect.